# What is the difference between a function invoked on an object and a function invoked through an object?

Tags: javascript

Reading a book about javascript (I don't know if the rules permit me to write the title and the author...) I notice something about functions that I would like to understand better:

> If a function is assigned to the property of an object, it is known as a method of that
>   object. When a function is invoked on or through an object, that object is the invocation
>   context or this value for the function.

I would like to understand what is the difference between a function invoked **on** an object and a function invoked **through** an object.

Comment: it means the same thing.

Comment: Hope this link will provide good explanation [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp)

Comment: @Thennarasan — It doesn't describe the things the question is asking about at all (and W3Schools is generally terrible anyway)

Comment: No. The rules don't *permit* you to post title and author, they *force* you to state them when you quote from the test. And without them, your question cannot be answered since we are missing context.

Comment: My *guess* is that the author meant both terms are used for the same thing: "invoke a function on an object" and "invoke a function through an object" mean the same. If not, he might refer to the difference between `obj.function()` and `function.call(obj)`.